# update trigger issue in oracle pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating an update trigger on a table called `tax_table` and inserting `:new` and  `:old` values into `update_audit_table`.
How can I incorporate related fields (`employee id` from `employee` table) into `update_audit_table` in the same insert.

```sql
CREATE  UPDAT_TAX_TRIG 
AFTER UPDATE
   ON tax_table
   FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO update_audit_table(PREV_TAX_CODE, OLD_TAX_CODE)
   VALUES(:NEW.PREV_TAX_CODE, OLD:PREV_TAX_CODE);
END;
```

```
update_audit_table:

employee_id,
employee_name,
prev_tax_code,
old_tax_code

employee table :
employee_id,
employee_name
```

I am trying to include fields from `employee` table into `update_audit_table` while inserting audit record.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for all 3 tables (including the `tax_table` table) as currently there is no correlation between tax and employees so it is unclear how you would merge the two into the audit table.

Answer (score 0):

As you have currently described the tables, it is impossible as there is no correlation that has been described between the `tax_table` and the `employee` table that would let you join the two.

However, if we assume that `tax_table` has an `employee_id` column then you can use that:

```sql
CREATE  UPDAT_TAX_TRIG 
  AFTER UPDATE ON tax_table
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO update_audit_table(
     employee_id,
     employee_name,
     PREV_TAX_CODE,
     OLD_TAX_CODE
  ) VALUES(
    :NEW.employee_id,
    (SELECT employee_name FROM employees WHERE employee_id = :NEW.employee_id),
    :NEW.PREV_TAX_CODE,
    :OLD.PREV_TAX_CODE
  );
END;
/
```

If it does not then you need to work out how the `tax_table` relates to an `employee`.

Comment: Thank you.... tax_table has  employee_id , prev_tax_code, old_tax_code in that case can you please explain the solution.